# Using async correctly while accessing AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, asyncstorage

I'm working on a React Native app which uses `jwt tokens` to access my backend API. I'm trying to save the token in `AsyncStorage` but looks like I'm not using `async` correctly.

I have a utility that helps me set my `fetch` options and this is where I'm trying to also grab the `jwt token` from `AsyncStorage` but I haven't been able to use `async` correctly to get the token. Either I'm ending up with what looks like an unresolved promise or getting an error that tells me that I'm using `await` incorrectly.

I could use some help in reading my `jwt token` correctly in my `fetch` utility.

Here's what my utility looks like:

```
import { getAccessToken } from '../utils/my-utils';

export const fetchOptionsGet = async () => {

    getAccessToken().then(token => {

        return {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
            }
        };
    });
}
```

And this is the code for `getAccessToken()` function:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export const getAccessToken = async () => {

    const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");

    return accessToken;
};
```

I think the issue is that because I'm calling an `async` function from my `fetchOptionsGet()` function, it becomes an `async` function as well. In my API method, when I tried to call it with an `await` keyword, I get a compile error. If I wrap my `fetch` call to my API inside a `.then(token => { // API call here })`, then I get a `react-redux` error telling me that my function should return a simple object.

What's the right way to read my `jwt token` and use it in my `fetch` call?

Comment: Looks like you need an `await` in the `fetchOptionsGet()`

Comment: I'm using a `.then()`. Isn't that essentially the same thing? Also when I try `const token = await getAccessToken();` I get an error that reads await is a reserved word.

Comment: What happens if you make `fetchOptionsGet` not asynchronous?

Comment: Just tried that but now I'm getting an `await is a reserved word` error inside the `fetchOptionsGet()` function. As far as I know, I need `async` for a function if I'm using `await` inside of it.

Comment: Hang on, im gonna try and sift through a project I just did. I ran into a similar problem

Comment: I'm not clear. Could you show me in code what you mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const fetchOptionsGet = async () => {

    const token = await getAccessToken();
    return {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
}
```

`await` waits for the promise to resolve. Then you can return whatever you need to return.

Comment: Interesting! This is exactly what I had before and was getting an error. I closed my emulator and started fresh and now this is working but getting another strange error i.e. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'volume' of null`

Comment: Are you debugging on a browser?

Comment: Try disabling your extensions.

Comment: One by one? Is there a way to disable all of them? I also see a "Developer Mode".

Comment: Developer mode is for developing chrome extensions. Check out [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-extensions-tempor/lcfdefmogcogicollfebhgjiiakbjdje?hl=en) as a possible option to disable all extensions quickly.

Comment: Oh the irony :-) An extension to disable extensions :-) Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
export const fetchOptionsGet = async () => {
const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
return {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
  }
};
```